# How to save output of for loop to list in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, scapy

```
allpkts = []
for i in range(10):
        s[IP].len = i
        del s[IP].chksum
        del s[UDP].chksum
        allpkts.append(s)
print allpkts
```

Here in my `allpkts` list I am seeing only last number output.
i want all the packets 0 to 9 in allpkts.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what's `s`? `IP`? `UDP`?

Comment: What is s and what output are you getting? You appear to be just appending the same thing to the list 10 times

Comment: s is the packet I am trying to manipulate, I am changing the IP length of packet 10 times. my output should be 10 packets with IP length 1 for 1st packet, 2 for 2nd packet, and so on. But it is appending IP length as 10 for all the packets in the list. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're not making a copy of `s`, so each iteration modifies the same packet.

Comment: And `allpkts` contains 10 references to that packet, not 10 different packets.

Comment: Answer for this question will be easy. But you need to explain it in more detail, you dont have character limit. Just try to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of `s` in each iteration. Otherwise you're repeatedly modifying the same packet, not putting different packets in the list.

```
allpkts = []
for i in range(10):
    stemp = s.copy()
    stemp[IP].len = i
    del stemp[IP].chksum
    del stemp[UDP].chksum
    allpkts.append(stemp)
print allpkts
```